# IntegrityError + django

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have created a django application. The application has a registration form. I inserted a jQuery plugin for birthday picker. But now when i fill the registration form and save it throws this error "**IntegrityError at /registrationForm/

(1048, "Column 'birthday' cannot be null") "** . I will paste my code here.

**registrationForm.html**

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://10.1.0.90:8080/static/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://10.1.0.90:8080/static/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://10.1.0.90:8080/static/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://10.1.0.90:8080/static/bday-picker.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready (function() {
        //$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $("#picker1").birthdaypicker({});
    });
   //Created / Generates the captcha function    
    function DrawCaptcha()
    {
    var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';
    var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';       
    var c = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
    var d = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
    var e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
    var f = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
    var g = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10)+ '';  
    var code = a + ' ' + b + ' ' + ' ' + c + ' ' + d + ' ' + e + ' '+ f + ' ' + g;
    document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").value = code
    }

    // Validate the Entered input aganist the generated security code function   
    function ValidCaptcha(){
        var str1 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtCaptcha').value);
        var str2 = removeSpaces(document.getElementById('txtInput').value);
        if (str1 == str2) return true;        
        return false;

    }

    // Remove the spaces from the entered and generated code
    function removeSpaces(string)
    {
        return string.split(' ').join('');
    }

    </script>
</head>
<title>Login/Registration Page</title>
<body bgcolor="#736F6E" onLoad="DrawCaptcha();">
<div align="center">
<form name="userInputForm" method="POST" id="myFormid" action="http://10.1.0.90:8080/login/">
  <div style="float:left;width:100%;">
    <p style="float:left;margin-right:10px;width:auto;">
      <label style="float:left;">Email id</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" name="username" size="25" />
    </p>
    <p style="float:left;margin-right:10px;width:auto;">
      <label style="float:left;">Password</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="password" name="password" size="25" />
      {% if invalid %}
      Mismatch in your email/password. 
      {% endif %} </p>
  </div>

  <p style="clear:both;float:left;">
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" style="float:left;margin-right:4px;"/>&nbsp;
    {% load facebookconnect %}
    {% facebook_connect_login_button %}
    {% facebook_connect_script %}

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a HREF="http://10.1.0.90:8080/forgotPassword/">Forgotten your password?</a></p>
  </div>
</form>
<br>

<br>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
function userCheck(){
    /*document.getElementById('myFormid').action = "http://10.1.0.90:8080/login/";
    if ((document.userInputForm.username.value.length==0)) */
}
</script>
<form name ="myform"  method="POST" id='FormID'>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstName" value=""  maxlength="100" />
      <b id="firstNameID" style="font-family:Times New Roman;color:#B4045F;font-size:14px;"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Last name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lastName" value="" maxlength="100" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>E-mail</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" maxlength="100" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="100"  />
      <b id="passwordID" style="font-family:Times New Roman;color:#B4045F;font-size:14px;"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Re-Type Password</td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password1" value="" maxlength="100"  />
      <b id="passwordID1" style="font-family:Times New Roman;color:#B4045F;font-size:14px;"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gender:</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />
      Male
      <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" />
      Female </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Birthday</td>
    <td><!--<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" value="" maxlength="100" />-->
<div class="picker" id="picker1" name="birthday" value=""></div>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

  <td width="150">Captcha</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="txtCaptcha" 
            style="background-image:url(1.jpg); text-align:center; border:1px;
            font-weight:bold; font-family:Modern" />
      <input type="button" id="btnrefresh" value="Refresh" onClick="DrawCaptcha();" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter above text</td>
        <td style="float:left;"><input type="text" id="txtInput" value="" maxlength="100" />
      <b id="textcaptcha" style="font-family:Times New Roman;color:#B4045F;font-size:14px;"> </td>
    </tr>



</table>


</form>



<div style="width:200; float:left; margin:20px 0 0 155px;">
  <input type="button" value="Sign Up" onClick="isEmpty();"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function isEmpty(){
    if  ((document.myform.firstName.value.length==0)) 
        {
        document.getElementById('firstNameID').innerHTML = 'Please fill this field';
        return true;
        }
    else if ((document.myform.password.value.length==0)) 
        {
        document.getElementById('passwordID').innerHTML = 'Please fill this field';
        return true;
        }
    else if (document.myform.password.value != document.myform.password1.value)
        {
        document.getElementById('passwordID1').innerHTML = 'Password mismatch';
        return true;
        }
    else if (! ValidCaptcha())
        {
            document.getElementById('textcaptcha').innerHTML = 'Please fill the captcha correctly';
        }

    else 
        { 
        document.getElementById('FormID').action = "http://10.1.0.90:8080/registrationForm/";
        document.getElementById('FormID').submit();
        return false; 
        }
}
</script><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

**views**

```
def registrationForm(request):
    if request.method == "POST":  
        firstName = request.POST.get("firstName")
        lastName = request.POST.get("lastName")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        sex = request.POST.get("sex")
        birthday = request.POST.get("birthday")
        UniversityDetails(firstName=firstName,lastName=lastName,email=email,password=password,sex=sex,birthday=birthday).save()

        send_mail('Email Verification', 'You have registered successfully', 'rv@gmail.com',
    [email], fail_silently=False)

        return render_to_response('login.html')

    return render_to_response("registrationForm.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

field `birthday` must have an input to be submitted with the form.

So either use:

```
<td>Birthday</td>
<td><input type="text" id="picker1" name="birthday" value="" 
           maxlength="100" class="picker" />
```

or use a hidden input for `birthday` and fill it with javascript when submitting.

Also, you don't validate the model in the view before saving and this is bad.

Try using [`django forms`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs), they are very handy both in the template and in the view.

### Update:

I checked the `birthdaypicker` plugin and it has an interesting option `hiddenDate` that can create a hidden input in the form for you named `birthdate`. You can do the following:

revert back to using `div` for the `birthdaypicker`:

```
<td>Birthday</td>
<td><!--<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker"
                        value="" maxlength="100" />-->
    <div class="picker" id="picker1" name="birthday" value=""></div>
```

when creating the `birthdaypicker` pass the `hiddendate` option:

```
  $(document).ready (function() {
    //$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $("#picker1").birthdaypicker({hiddenDate: true});
});
```

and in `django` view, use `birthdate` instead of `birthday`

```
birthday = request.POST.get("birthdate")
```

Comment: thanks manji..this fixes my error..but the birthday values r not saved in my db..can u tell me why its not getting saved in database?

Comment: what value do ou see in the code? Why aren't you using Django Forms? It's much better than keeping track yourself of every thing and it will do the validation for you?

Comment: i want to save the birthday entered in database. Now the form submission is happening, but when i checked the database using django admins, birthday field stays blank. I am a newbie in django, so didnt knew about django forms when i started doing this app

Comment: can you check the value of `birthday` just before the `save` instruction? (`print birthday` will echo the value in the server console)

Comment: I checked the `birthdaypicker` plugin and it's building 3 select for day/month/year, that's why you're not getting anything. It has an interesting option `hiddenDate` that create a hidden input in the form for you named `birthdate`, you can use that, see my edit.

Comment: that was perfect...that worked ..!! thanks a lot Manji..u r really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line here:

```
<div class="picker" id="picker1" name="birthday" value=""></div>
```

This will not be submitted along with your form. You need to put a hidden input to store the birthday value, so it can be passed along with the POST data.

```
<input type="hidden" name="birthday" value="" />
<div class="picker" id="picker1"></div>
```

Then, when you select a date from the date picker, add in hook to update the value of this hidden input.

**Edit**

I would also recommend rewriting your Django view like this, to make it more manageable, and hook into Django's built in form validation:

```
from django import forms

class DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = UniversityDetails

def registrationForm(request):
  form = DetailsForm()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DetailsForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
      send_mail('Email Verification', 'You have registered successfully', 'rv@gmail.com', [email], fail_silently=False)
      form.save()

      return render_to_response('login.html')

  return render_to_response("registrationForm.html")
```

Comment: Thanks Gary..That fixed my error. But the value is not getting saved in database.Can you tell me how to get it solved ?

Comment: Are you definitely setting the value of the hidden input when you select a date from the date picker?

Comment: thanks for the edit Gary, but i am almost done with my application. Can you help me to do that with my original code?. i understand your method is much simpler n straight forward :), but changing my code takes some tym for me to understand and does the same change for whole app.